# Notification sound doesn't play when device screen is locked

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a notification (instance of `Notification`) with sound (set with `NotificationCompat.Builder.setSound(Uri sound)`. If screen (or device you know) is unlocked and notification is generated I can hear sound too but if screen is locked and notification is generated I hear nothing. Is this because notifications are only generated when screen is unlocked because they are "visible notifications" or I can do it hearable when sreen is locked? If not how can I generate sound notification when screen is locked? Thanks!

Comment: I heard that this property's name is Specific Push and I'm searching it, too.

Comment: i have a same problem when i am making a android application using FCM messaging service when my phone is locked then notiification come doesn't have sound in android studio

Comment: has anyone got a solution?